# Is there any way to store temporary list values in c# 4.5?

Tags: c#, asp.net, wpf, list

I need to store list values impermanent and i need to get to that list values in another c# class. the procedure resemble, Session in Asp.net. Anybody please share a few thoughts regarding this idea.

Here is my code:

class1.cs:

```
    ObservableCollection<SampleEntityList> zoneList = new ObservableCollection<SampleEntityList>();
    ObservableCollection<SampleEntityList> ztowList = new ObservableCollection<SampleEntityList>();
```

I need to store this 2 list values some place locally and i need to get to this two list values to another class.. be that as it may, i would prefer not to go as constructor. I need to store this two rundown values locally..

class2.cs:

??

I have endeavored this code:

Made new static class for setting the Property. What's more, I can't get to the property access outside the class..

Here's my code:

```
static class GlobalTempStorageVariable
{

    ObservableCollection<SampleEntityList> zoneListGlobal
                                    = new ObservableCollection<SampleEntityList>();
    ObservableCollection<SampleEntityList> ztowListGlobal
                                    = new ObservableCollection<SampleEntityList>();


    public static ObservableCollection<SampleEntityList> CurrentListOfInventories
    {
        get { return zoneListGlobal; }
        set { zoneListGlobal = value; }
    }

    public static ObservableCollection<SampleEntityList> CurrentSelectedInventories
    {
        get { return ztwoListGlobal; }
        set { ztwoListGlobal= value; }
    }

  }
```

But this code is not working. Also i am unable to access CurrentListOfInventories & CurrentSelectedInventories outside the class..

class1.cs:

```
   GlobalTempStorageVariable. ???(its not showing the property)..
```

Any help would be appreciated..

Comment: Thats a bad practice. Read http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/God_object However you can store it in static class or property. Make zoneList static public in class1, then access it like class1.zoneList in class2, without creating class1 instance in class2.

Comment: could you please read my edited post again?

Comment: @RajDeInno don't use properties, but static methods that returns your objects. Look at my answer how to perform it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Static property cannot access non-static field, zoneListGlobal and ztowListGlobal should also be static in order to be accessible by their Properties :

```
static class GlobalTempStorageVariable
{
    static ObservableCollection<SampleEntityList> zoneListGlobal
                                    = new ObservableCollection<SampleEntityList>();

    static ObservableCollection<SampleEntityList> ztowListGlobal
                                    = new ObservableCollection<SampleEntityList>();

    public static ObservableCollection<SampleEntityList> CurrentListOfInventories
    {
        get { return zoneListGlobal; }
        set { zoneListGlobal = value; }
    }

    public static ObservableCollection<SampleEntityList> CurrentSelectedInventories
    {
        get { return ztowListGlobal; }
        set { ztowListGlobal = value; }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can build your static class with 2 static methods that return your desired object, like this example:

```
public static class GlobalTempStorageVariable
{

    ObservableCollection<SampleEntityList> zoneListGlobal
                                    = new ObservableCollection<SampleEntityList>();
    ObservableCollection<SampleEntityList> ztowListGlobal
                                    = new ObservableCollection<SampleEntityList>();


    public static ObservableCollection<SampleEntityList> GetCurrentListOfInventories()
    {
        return zoneListGlobal;
    }

    public static ObservableCollection<SampleEntityList> GetCurrentSelectedInventories()
    {
        return ztowListGlobal;
    }

}
```